# Calculating integrer x and y coordinates around point by range variable

Tags: c++, arrays, 2d, coordinates

The problem didn't let me sleep at night.

Given floating point x and y coordinates of infinite 2D space, and the range variable, I need to get all possible intergrer coordinates that are in range.
[image]

The green blocks are in range, and the red ones are not.

Now, I have an answer, but I'm not sure if it's the best one.
Make an 2D array with all the values in a square around the point (from -distance, distance to distance, -distance) and then iterate through the entire array, each time checking the distance if it is closer or further than needed, and if so then insert it into another array.

Comment: You might lookup "Circle Lattice Points" and "Gauss circle problem"

Comment: More related is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Starting from the center point, go both ways horizontally to the furthest points that are in the range.
- For each of these points encountered, calculate the maximum vertical coordinate either way which will still be in the range, and add all the squares along this line.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: while this is the right answer, Im going to also modify it a bit, since I can add 8 (or 4 at horizontal, vertical and diagonal lines to center) squares just by swapping the x and y around at same time, while checking the distance only once.

Comment: @ImAlive good idea. I only showed a schematic approach, but yes you should exploit the symmetries of the circle